# Touchscreen multitouch works in XWayland but not Xorg

Tags: touchscreen, 18.10, multi-touch

I have a Thinkpad X1 Tablet running Ubuntu 18.10. Using two fingers to scroll, zoom around, etc works great (in e.g. Chromium) when running under XWayland, but only a single touch point seems to be recognized under Xorg.

Running `xinput test-xi2 <device-id>` shows TouchEvent's on Wayland, but ButtonEvent's on Xorg, so it appears that my touchscreen is configured wrong and Xorg is interpreting the touchscreen as a mouse.

Any idea how to configure Xorg to view the touchscreen as, well, a touchscreen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! It is just this bug, reported here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xf86-input-wacom/+bug/1774242

I summarize here:

`/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-wacom.conf` as shipped, has this:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Wacom touchscreen class"
    MatchProduct "Wacom|WACOM|PTK-540WL|ISD-V4"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    MatchIsTouchscreen "true"
    Driver "wacom"
EndSection
```

and also perhaps an entry for Wacom USB touchscreen class. This causes the touchscreen to use the Wacom driver instead of the much better `libinput` driver. Simply removing that whole section, as well as the USB one, got my touchscreen working wonderfully!